# Browser Opera does not play html5 audio mp3 locally (on computer)

Tags: javascript, html, audio, html5-audio, opera

Today, unexpectedly for myself, I noticed that Opera stopped playing html5 audio (mp3-file) locally on computer. That is, if you upload the code and mp3-file to the server, it plays normally, but when you open the same html file with the audio tag and link locally, it does not work anymore. That is, this code (for example):

```
<audio src="assets/test.mp3" controls></audio>
```

On server this works without problems, locally on the computer does not play. Who knows what is the reason? Really CORS? For example, in Chrome that works without problems both locally and on the server.

Comment: what OS are you on ?

Comment: Does `<audio src="test.mp3" controls></audio>` work locally if you put html and mp3 in same location (not using **assets** sub-folder)?

Answer (score 0):

If you're on Linux, see the permissions of the mp3 file. If it's something like `-rw-------` it won't play, because the PHP user should be able to read it, i.e. it needs something like `-rw-r--r--`.